# Neo4j data export from Windows to Linux machines

Tags: linux, centos, neo4j

I have embedded Neo4j, modelled the data in Windows machine. My production database server is on centos. So, I need to move the data(Folder X)  from windows machine to CentOS.

**The problem that I am facing:**  Even if on the linux machine, I pointed the data base (by changing the server configuration location) to the data folder X, Neo4j doesn't recognize that data.

Is it because the format of files  data created for Neo4j is different from that in Linux .

Please help.

Comment: double posting doesn't help  getting better answers, just supply the concrete information on your original question

Comment: Michael,Can we chat, so that I better explain my problem.